# A classical Latin phrase for "all or nothing"

Tags: classical-latin, idiom, passage-request

Is there a saying in classical Latin similar to "all or nothing"?
I am aware of [*aut Caesar aut nihil*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_phrases_(A)#aut_Caesar_aut_nihil), and that would be fine if it was classical.
In most cases the era of origin is irrelevant, but I would like to know whether a similar quote is found in classical authors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking the following as an example:

> *seu nihil militi, sive omnia concederentur*
>
> concede either nothing to the army, or everything

Tacitus, *Annals*, 1.36

we could perhaps adapt it to: *seu nihil sive omnia*

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a phrase from classical Latin, but I should think that *nihil nisi omnia* would be all right. The meaning is quite clear, and it sounds snappy enough.